# For OpenCV, my Python code can display webcam, but my C++ cannot

Tags: python, c++, opencv, webcam

I'm on Windows 10 64-bit with OpenCV 3.3.1,Python 3,the latest C++, and Visual Studio 2017.

Here is my Python 3 code that properly displays my webcam:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ret, last_frame = cap.read()
row, col, ch = last_frame.shape

if last_frame is None:
    exit()

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if frame is None:
        exit()

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(33) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Below is a C++ code that does not display my webcam. This code only displays a grey frame:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // 1st device, DSHOW
    while (cap.isOpened())
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;
        imshow("ocv", frame);

        int k = waitKey(10);
        if (k == 27) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please help me with this issue? I tried modifying my C++ to VideoCapture cap(1), VideoCapture cap(2), VideoCapture cap(3), and VideoCapture cap but I still get no live video from my webcam.

Screenshot of my running Python Code:
[image: Python Code]

Screenshot of my running C++ Code:
[image: Cpp Code]

Comment: I find it strange, your code is correct, check if you are missing some dll, you could also explain how you have installed opencv

Comment: For a quick response regarding my OpenCV installation for C++ and Visual Studio 2017, I followed the instructions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-VHaLHC4XI&index=2&list=FLjVqE1--vLc0CuYgAI4QxZw&t=0s. The instructions are also available here in text: https://www.deciphertechnic.com/install-opencv-with-visual-studio/ I can elaborate more on my installation process if it helps.

Comment: Try running a release build instead of a debug build as folks sometimes get their library linking mixed up.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I set the Solution Configuration to Release, but that just creates red wiggly lines on my #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

Comment: That suggests your settings are different between debug and release and slightly wrong at least. You need to check the setting for where "include" (or "header") files are located - sorry I don't use MS products so I can't tell you the actual name. Check your DLL and linker settings too.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got my webcam to show up properly for Visual Studio C++ OpenCV. Here's what I did:

1. Install Visual Studio 2015 with C++ and Python Tools.
2. Download and extract OpenCV 3.4.2
3. Add to Path C:\<...>\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin
4. In Visual Studio 2015, create a Win32 CONSOLE Application.
5. Right click on your project and select properties. Makes the following changes:

a. C/C++ - General - Additional Include Directories: C:\<...>\opencv\build\include

b. Linker - General - Additional Library Directories: C:\<...>\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib

c. Linker - Input: opencv_world342d.lib

Thank you everyone for your response!