# opencv VideoCapture() couldn't open on c++ by opened by python

Tags: c++, opencv, conan

Good day,

### `c++`

I installed `opencv/4.5.2` from conan (by cmake [macro](https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/raw/v0.15/conan.cmake)) and try a simple piece of [code](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html):

```cpp
cv::VideoCapture cap(0, cv::CAP_MSMF);
if (!cap.isOpened()) {
    cerr << "couldn't open\n";
    return -1; // <<-- stop here
}
// ...
```

```
# ...
conan_cmake_run(
            REQUIRES
            ${CONAN_EXTRA_REQUIRES}
            opencv/4.5.2
            OPTIONS
            ${CONAN_EXTRA_OPTIONS}
            BASIC_SETUP
            CMAKE_TARGETS # individual targets to link to
            BUILD
            missing)
```

The same result in debug and [release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335082/for-opencv-my-python-code-can-display-webcam-but-my-c-cannot#comment89649200_51335082) building an executable.

### hardware

```
$ls -ltrh /dev/video*                                                                                                                                                                    
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 июн 27 22:26 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 июн 27 22:26 /dev/video0
```

### `python`

Same code on python works fine:

```py
import cv2


c = cv2.VideoCapture(0, 0)

while(True):
    r, frame = c.read()
    cv2.imshow('p', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
        

c.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

### Fix static `libjpeg-turbo` dependency

In order to satisfy `conan` and automatically generated cmake files
you should build static `libjpeg-turbo` library.

```
git clone https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo.git
cd libjpeg-turbo
cmake -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .
sudo cmake --install build --prefix /usr/
```

### OS

```
$uname -a
Linux omen 5.10.41-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 28 19:10:32 UTC 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### PS

Add user to `video` group or run `./main` as root didn't have any benefits.

### UPD1

```cpp
cv::utils::logging::setLogLevel(cv::utils::logging::LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);
std::cout << cv::getBuildInformation();
return 0;
```

The both logs for release|debug build `Video I/O` sections are empty. But python has the following section:

```
Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (58.109.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.61.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.60.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.8.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
```

### UPD2

This is logging after `VideoCapture cap(0, cv::CAP_ANY)`

```
[DEBUG:0] global /home/user/.conan/data/opencv/4.5.2/_/_/build/82e231b59ebe3f3bd9c050e2b1b60042669442a6/source_subfolder/modules/videoio/src/videoio_registry.cpp (191) VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Builtin backends(7): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); MSMF(970); CV_IMAGES(960); CV_MJPEG(950); UEYE(940)
[DEBUG:0] global /home/user/.conan/data/opencv/4.5.2/_/_/build/82e231b59ebe3f3bd9c050e2b1b60042669442a6/source_subfolder/modules/videoio/src/videoio_registry.cpp (215) VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Available backends(7): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); MSMF(970); CV_IMAGES(960); CV_MJPEG(950); UEYE(940)
[ INFO:0] global /home/user/.conan/data/opencv/4.5.2/_/_/build/82e231b59ebe3f3bd9c050e2b1b60042669442a6/source_subfolder/modules/videoio/src/videoio_registry.cpp (217) VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Enabled backends(7, sorted by priority): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); MSMF(970); CV_IMAGES(960); CV_MJPEG(950); UEYE(940)
[ INFO:0] global /home/user/.conan/data/opencv/4.5.2/_/_/build/82e231b59ebe3f3bd9c050e2b1b60042669442a6/source_subfolder/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (324) getPluginCandidates VideoIO plugin (GSTREAMER): glob is 'libopencv_videoio_gstreamer*.so', 1 location(s)
[ INFO:0] global /home/user/.conan/data/opencv/4.5.2/_/_/build/82e231b59ebe3f3bd9c050e2b1b60042669442a6/source_subfolder/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (331) getPluginCandidates     - ./cmake-build-debug/bin: 0
[ INFO:0] global /home/user/.conan/data/opencv/4.5.2/_/_/build/82e231b59ebe3f3bd9c050e2b1b60042669442a6/source_subfolder/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (335) getPluginCandidates Found 0 plugin(s) for GSTREAMER
[ INFO:0] global /home/user/.conan/data/opencv/4.5.2/_/_/build/82e231b59ebe3f3bd9c050e2b1b60042669442a6/source_subfolder/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (324) getPluginCandidates VideoIO plugin (MSMF): glob is 'libopencv_videoio_msmf*.so', 1 location(s)
[ INFO:0] global /home/user/.conan/data/opencv/4.5.2/_/_/build/82e231b59ebe3f3bd9c050e2b1b60042669442a6/source_subfolder/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (331) getPluginCandidates     - ./cmake-build-debug/bin: 0
[ INFO:0] global /home/user/.conan/data/opencv/4.5.2/_/_/build/82e231b59ebe3f3bd9c050e2b1b60042669442a6/source_subfolder/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (335) getPluginCandidates Found 0 plugin(s) for MSMF
[ INFO:0] global /home/user/.conan/data/opencv/4.5.2/_/_/build/82e231b59ebe3f3bd9c050e2b1b60042669442a6/source_subfolder/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (324) getPluginCandidates VideoIO plugin (UEYE): glob is 'libopencv_videoio_ueye*.so', 1 location(s)
[ INFO:0] global /home/user/.conan/data/opencv/4.5.2/_/_/build/82e231b59ebe3f3bd9c050e2b1b60042669442a6/source_subfolder/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (331) getPluginCandidates     - ./cmake-build-debug/bin: 0
[ INFO:0] global /home/user/.conan/data/opencv/4.5.2/_/_/build/82e231b59ebe3f3bd9c050e2b1b60042669442a6/source_subfolder/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (335) getPluginCandidates Found 0 plugin(s) for UEYE
```

Comment: Did you try with same apipreference ? using `cv::VideoCapture cap(0, 0);`

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried with full path to device or different type of APIs .

Comment: Then you may look to `cv::getBuildInformation()` to see if capture is build, or enable logging to see what goes on `cv::utils::logging::setLogLevel(utils::logging::LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);`

Comment: I added few logs...

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote before I use `conan` script to build `opencv`:

```
macro(run_conan)
    # Download automatically, you can also just copy the conan.cmake file
    if (NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
        message(STATUS "Downloading conan.cmake from https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan")
        file(DOWNLOAD "https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/raw/v0.15/conan.cmake" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
    endif ()

    include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake)

    conan_add_remote(
            NAME
            bincrafters
            URL
            https://api.bintray.com/conan/bincrafters/public-conan)

    conan_cmake_run(
            REQUIRES
            ${CONAN_EXTRA_REQUIRES}
            opencv/4.5.2
            fmt/8.0.0
            OPTIONS
            ${CONAN_EXTRA_OPTIONS}
            BASIC_SETUP
            CMAKE_TARGETS # individual targets to link to
            BUILD
            missing)
endmacro()
```

In Linux (manjaro in my case) you should install `pacman -S v4l-utils` and add somewhere in `CMakeLists.txt` instruction: `set(CONAN_EXTRA_OPTIONS ${CONAN_EXTRA_OPTIONS} opencv:with_v4l=True)`.

After that in section of `cv::getBuildInformation()` I have the following:

```
Video I/O:
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
```

And voila!